# Right to left and left to right languages in the same app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

To my understanding apple doesn't allow 2 identical apps in diferrent languages on the appstore but what if one language is left to right and the other is right to left? That means diferrent menus, different positioning of items, different UI etc' (even the segues are different). Obviously i can't use regualr localization for this. 
Is there a solution for that or I'm just going to write a very big app with a lot of "if user is using hebrew go to vc1 else go to vc2" ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider Auto Layout feature of iOS 6.0.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

"You don’t even have to specify new layout for languages like Hebrew and Arabic in which the left to right ordering of elements themselves should generally be reversed."

Comment: I want my app to be iOS 5 compatible.

Comment: also, With english my segues are left to right while in hebrew it's right to left. (that's a small example) I don't think you could do it with autolayout (even though it's not a possibility)

Comment: Autolayout offers some great features and is incredibly rich, but it comes with alarming complexities and interdependencies which are sometimes hard to keep track of. It seems like it shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: By the time you solve this problem *not* using AutoLayout, no one will be left using iOS 5.

Comment: In AutoLayout, you can use leading and trailing attributes which are  left and right in English but UI flips in a right to left environment like Hebrew.

Comment: apple wwdc 2013: 93% iOS have iOS6

Comment: as of iOS 9, segues are also flipped when running in an RTL language. I highly recommend using Base Internationalization with leading and trailing constraints in your project to achieve what you desire.