# Multi Language Design support in IOS

Tags: ios, multilingual

I want to develop ios app which support multi language, country wise.

So when app will supporting English language, its design should be left to right and when app will supporting arabic language for example then, design/text should be right to left.

So any body has any idea for this functionality? Or we need to manage it programmatically manage?

Thanks,

Hardik Shah

Comment: Autolayout can do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike Weller mentioned in his comment, Autolayout should do this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1

"You don’t even have to specify new layout for languages like Hebrew and Arabic in which the left to right ordering of elements themselves should generally be reversed."

This question seems to have been answered a couple of time before, including here:

[Right to left and left to right languages in the same app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215344/right-to-left-and-left-to-right-languages-in-the-same-app)

and here for determining which direction the language should be:

[iOS: Determine if device language is Right to Left (RTL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352342/ios-determine-if-device-language-is-right-to-left-rtl)